# Redis performance tunning

Tags: linux, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

I would like to use Redis server on Amazon EC2 instance.
When I run redis-benchmark locally, I'm getting 140K req/sec
When I run from another instance I'm getting 75K req/sec which is understandable cause of network latency.

To maximize instance utilization I start two redis servers, each on different CPU.
When I run two redis-benchmark utilities from two different instances, when each one connects to different redis-server (same instance, different CPUs), I'm getting about 30K-35K req/sec on each one.
So instead of expected raise in req/seq, it's same in total

The bandwidth of two redis-benchamrk is about 80Mb/s
And by checking with iperf, the instance is capable of ~1Gb/s
The CPUs is not under heavy load.
Also I tried to use 2 ENI's and "Receive Packet Steering" - nothing changed.

What I missing?

Thanks

Comment: How many CPU instances do you have at your server?

Comment: I tried instance with 4 and 8 cores
Two redis servers, each affined to single core

Comment: Depending on the instance type you might not be getting network priority. While the line might be capable of 1Gps in bursts at the time you tested, that's no guarantee. The more expensive instances get network priority over cheaper ones, that could affect what you're seeing.

Comment: I tried to run iperf simultaneously with redis-benchmark. And when limiting iperf to 500Mbs/sec for example, it not affecting redis reqest ratio.
So from my understanding, there is enough bandwidth for redis.
Also all the instances in same "placement group" and with "Enhanced Networking"

Comment: have you tried 2 redis instances and 2 redis-benchmark instances locally on a 4-core machine? Also, try pipelining as well and see if affects things (e.g. -P 100) it should get higher results regarding, but I'm wondering if it would make the overall gain of 2 instances vs. 1 more significant.

Comment: Yes, locally redis working good. Each one getting 130K-140K req/sec without affecting each other.

Comment: Ok so it's a networking issue for sure. Now the question is whether it's internal to the machines or not (probably not), and whether it's fixable.